# Merging a local repo with a Github project

Tags: git, github, repository, upgrade

I have a local github repository that is an old version of an open-source project on Github. 
I need to upgrade my local repository with the new version on github but I don't know where to start.

I saw an example where I use the command "git remote add {name} {URL of github repository}". Is this correct? Do I replace the field {name} with my local repository?

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

I am new to github and I don't want to ruin my local repository so I am hoping someone who has experience can offer some advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add the remote repository (I've called it `upstream` here, you could call it everything):

   ```
   git remote add upstream {URL of github repository}
   ```
2. Fetch all the commits, branches, tags, etc. from the `upstream` remote repo. This is a safe command and does not destroy your local repo's history or your working-tree.

   ```
   git fetch upstream
   ```
3. You could run `git log upstream/BRANCH_NAME` or `git log upstream/TAG_NAME` to see the list of commits for the given `BRANCH_NAME` or `TAG_NAME` on the remote `upstream`. In fact for any of the git commands, if you want to refer to the branch present in the remote `upstream`, use the `upstream/<BRANCH_NAME>` syntax. For tags, `tags/TAG_NAME` should suffice.
4. If you want to merge or rebase changes from these tags or branches into your local repo, you could do so using the `merge` and `rebase` commands. Let me know if you need more help on these commands.

Comment: I followed your commands and I get lost when I want to merge a specific tag. I see the tag name listed that I want to merge with my repo. Do I do something like "git merge --tag <tag name>"?

Comment: Oh, I think I do this "git merge tags/<tag name>". I tried this and it may have work. Is that right?

Comment: Thanks for all the help. The "git merge tags/tag_name" seemed to do the trick :)

Comment: Yes if you've checked out any of the branches in your repo, and you want to merge an upstream tag named FOO you would do `git merge tags/FOO`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is correct

```
git remote add upstream git://github.com/antirez/redis.git
```

The `name` part is just a 
[name you pick](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html)
so that it is easy to refer to.

```
    Adds a remote named <name> for the repository at <url>. The command
    git fetch <name> can then be used to create and update
    remote-tracking branches <name>/<branch>.
```

Comment: What if I need to grab a particular tag of the github repository? Is there a way a specifying the particular version with this command? It looks like based on the manual page I can use --tags?

Comment: I tried the command with '--tags', the name of the tag, and the url to the open-source github project but nothing happened. My local private repo is also github and what I did notice is that the command edited my .git/config on my private github local project. Do I need to change my .git/config file to point to the open-source project?